# Помогите разобраться с протоколом для фитнес трекера

Tags: swift4, protocol

Пытаюсь сделать модель данных для фитнес-трекера. Он снимает пульс и показывает его в приложении. Надо проверять, что выводится на экран пользователю.

Для этого вначале делаю условный пример пульса с помощью функции генерации случайных чисел и вывожу показания в консоль и на экран приложения на label. А потом это значение надо снять с label и напечатать еще раз в консоли для проверки.

В итоге, в консоли через каждые две секунды должно выводиться по две строки - одна "The most recent heart rate reading is ..." и вторая - "The user has been shown a heart rate of ..."

Код ниже:

```
import UIKit

protocol HeartRateReceiverDelegate {
    func heartRateUpdated(to bpm: Int)
}

class HeartRateReceiver {
    var delegate: HeartRateReceiverDelegate?
    var currentHR: Int? {
        didSet {
            if let currentHR = currentHR {
                print("The most recent heart rate reading is \(currentHR).")
                delegate?.heartRateUpdated(to: currentHR)
            } else {
                print("Looks like we can't pick up a heart rate.")
            }
        }
    }
    func startHeartRateMonitoringExample() {
        for _ in 1...10 {
            let randomHR = 60 + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(15)))
            currentHR = randomHR
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2)
        }
    }
}

class HeartRateViewController: UIViewController, HeartRateReceiverDelegate {
    var heartRateLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    func heartRateUpdated(to bpm: Int) {
        heartRateLabel.text = "The user has been shown a heart rate of \(bpm)"
        print(heartRateLabel.text!)
    }
}

let heartRateReceiver = HeartRateReceiver()
heartRateReceiver.startHeartRateMonitoringExample()

var heartRateViewController = HeartRateViewController()

heartRateReceiver.delegate = heartRateViewController
```

Подскажите, что здесь не так?

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Не приходят данные или не отображаются?

Comment: свойство delegate  все время nil  и не печатает вторую строку, которая говорит, что "The user has been shown a heart rate of"

Answer (score 1):

ошибка найдена. Оказывается нужно было вызов функции

```
heartRateReceiver.startHeartRateMonitoringExample()
```

поставить в самом конце.

Но остался все-таки вопрос по протоколу. Каким образом он здесь работает? В частности, зачем нужно делегату присваивать содержание экземпляра вью контролера?

```
heartRateReceiver.delegate = heartRateViewController
```

Ведь свойство delegate  в экземпляре первого класса уже получает значение?

```
delegate?.heartRateUpdated(to: currentHR)
```

Какова в целом последовательность выполнения кода в этом примере? Я так понимаю, что вначале стартует функция с условными данными:

```
heartRateReceiver.startHeartRateMonitoringExample()
```

Она делает в цикле десять проходов и передает в каждой итерации значение в переменную currentHR. Та в свою очередь развертывает опционал в условии и печатает первую строку с текущим показанием пульса.

```
if let currentHR = currentHR {
                print("The most recent heart rate reading is \(currentHR).")
```

И здесь же значение currentHR присваивается как параметр функции в свойство delegate.

```
delegate?.heartRateUpdated(to: currentHR)
```

Оттуда оно попадает в экземпляр вьюконтролера, присваивается на Label и затем с него печатается в консоль.

И получается, что программа здесь уже все  выполняет. И если все уже выполнено, то зачем тогда еще присваивать значение вьюконтролера свойству delegate?